# PHP if else statement producing unwanted line breaks

Tags: php, if-statement, line-breaks

I'm using a PHP if else statement to ignore a custom field 'thingstodo' if it's empty. I have got the following code to work but it's putting unwanted line-breaks after every paragraph tag in my content. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php if (get_field('gettingthere')): ?>
    <div class="inprofile3col">
        <h2>Getting there</h2>
        <span class="content">
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gettingthere', true); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- ends Getting there -->
    <!-- Things to do begins -->
    <?php if (get_field('thingstodo')): ?> 
        <h2>Things to do</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="content">
        <?php
        $value = get_field('thingstodo');
        if ($value) {
            echo $value;
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
        ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
<span class="content">
<?php 
$value = get_field('thingstodo');
if ($value ) {echo $value ;} else {echo '';}
?>
</span>
```

you still have an output if the field is empty: the empty span-tag:

```
<span class="content">
echo '';
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove line breaks from thingstodo and avoid empty html tags. Here is the updated mark up:

```
   <?php if( get_field('gettingthere') ): ?>
    <div class="inprofile3col">
    <h2>Getting there</h2>
    <span class="content">
    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'gettingthere', true ) ; ?>
    </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- ends Getting there -->
    <!-- Things to do begins -->
    <?php if( get_field('thingstodo') && !empty(trim(get_field('thingstodo')))) { ?> 
    <h2>Things to do</h2>
    <span class="content">
    <?php 
    $value = preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ',trim(get_field('thingstodo')));    
    if ($value) {echo $value ;} else {echo '';}
    ?>
    </span>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've tried this solution and it doesn't change the outcome though I appreciate the smarter code.

Comment: Leaving empty tags in your html can yield undesired gaps. My code ensures thingstodo has a value before it outputs any tags. Your code was still outputting the span tag (at the end), regardless of whether thingstodo was empty. You said it didn't work though, are you sure thingstodo is actually empty?

Comment: Thanks. It's actually the output of thingstodo that has gaps. When thingstodo is empty your code works fine. I've checked the source code, there are no empty tags. It's not a huge problem,  it just looks sloppy.

Comment: Ok I've updated the code to remove line-breaks/extra spaces from thingstodo. Hopefully that solves it.

Comment: Thank you for trying again but still not working. I found that WP automatically adds these breaks which I didn't know before. Found this [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content